# Error when installing pycrypto

Tags: python, mingw, fabric, pycrypto

I'm trying to install Fabric on my PC (with Windows + setuptools). It was giving me an error, since I have older version of pycrypto.

When I was trying to install latest version I stumble upon "Unable to find vcvarsall.bat" error. I googled something about MinGW, so I installed that too. I've added it to my Windows PATH, but now i'm getting another error, which looks like this: "command 'gcc' failed: no such file or directory." What do i do now? Found something about gcc-mingw, which is some version of MinGW that could help?

Why is has to be so damn complicated :D.

---

New development. Managed to install pycrytpo and fabric, but still can't run anything in the latter. New error says: "ImportError: no module named win32api". Quick google search says something about PyWin, but easy_install can't find it and it looks like it's abandoned. Any ideas?

Comment: This is well after this question was asked, but having just encountered this problem myself, I was able to solve it with the binary files available here: http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto This might not be considered an answer if the issue is the lack of ability to compile, but it is if someone just wants pycrypto working right now.

Comment: For solving problem with `PyWin`, download [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20218/pywin32-218.zip/download), extract it and run `python setup.py install` in the extracted directory.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's so complicated because C (C++? Can't remember what they used at the moment, but I am pretty sure they used C) is much, much better at math than Python, so the math pieces of PyCrypto are all written in C. It does have a _slowmath module if the compiled versions aren't available, but it's name is telling... it is *much* slower.

gcc is the **GNU Compiler Collection** (<!-- an edit, I had thought it stood for *GNU C Compiler*, but apparently my knowledge was dated). It is a bit legendary, but apparently your version of Windows has not heard of it. First question though, have you closed the "DOS prompt" and restart it? (it's in quotes because the people at superuser once [yelled at me](https://superuser.com/questions/297678/dos-pauses-in-stdout-execution) because I did not sufficiently acknowledge its inferiority) Environment Variables in Windows do not update during a "DOS session" (or whatever it is supposed to be called).

If you have, chances are that it can be found inside of the MingW install director -- if there is a bin folder I'd check there first. If not, I would search for gcc.exe and make sure that it's path is part of PATH. Then,

If all else fails, you might be able to get more info on MingW [here](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/InstallationHOWTOforMinGW).

Comment: Just restarted command line. Let's just say that I feel very stupid now :). Anyway, new error!

Comment: @eryksun Yep. But my experience is that most people don't know the difference, and some look at you funny if you say "cmd.exe".